# Не изменяется QHBoxLayout

Tags: qt, qt5, qt4

В QHBoxLayout я вставил пару кнопок в конструкторе дизайну. И сделал коротким QHBoxLayout, так чтобы кнопки накладывались друг на друга. В конструкторе формы я прописал:
 ui->horizontalFrame_2->setGeometry( ui->stackedWidget->geometry() );
чтобы кнопки не накладывались друг на друга. Но кнопки далье накладываютса друг на друга. Как сделать чтобы они не накладивалься друг на друга?

Answer (score 1):

нужно так сделать: 
ui->horizontalFrame_2->setGeometry(QRect(
         0,0,
         ui->stackedWidget->geometry().width(),
         ui->stackedWidget->geometry().height()));